# Android/Java How to read this file on website?

Tags: java, android, file, parsing, memory

### www.rgrfm.be/rgrsite/maxradio/android.php

### www.rgrfm.be/rgrsite/maxradio/onair.txt

The track information of the music being played is contained in onair.txt. android.php is a php script I wrote.

I need to display the track information in my Android application. I do not want do download it to disk but keep it in memory. I don't know if the php script is useless because it would create additional overhead. So it's probably better to simply parse onair.txt

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://www.rgrfm.be/rgrsite/maxradio/onair.txt").openStream();
```

I am stuck with this. Has anyone got time to help me?

Comment: How about writing a PHP script which reads the text file and give you back in the form of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

As described, php script seems useless. Since, you can directly read the text file. So, first read it as text, then parse it.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.rgrfm.be/rgrsite/maxradio/onair.txt");
String text = readAsText(url)
parse(text);

String readAsText(URL url) {
  // read the url as text here.
}

void parse(String text) {

}
```